# How do I precompile assets in rails in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to manually precompile some assets in my dev environment (to check the content of the compiled js and css files) from the command line.

I am running

`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

but my js and css are not compiled in the public/assets folder, only the images are. Any idea why that may be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this to your `config/environments/production.rb` :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

Comment: No problem. You might want to specify some files instead of `*.css`. It's up to you.

Comment: I actually had this specified in production. Just didn't realize it was the reason.