# rails is not compiling my assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

My rails application is not compiling my assets. I followed many similar questions but none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

I'm running in development environment.

This is what I get:

**HTML**:

```
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS**:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
// 
//= require_tree ./svgweb
//= require modernizr
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#content').children('svg').size() > 0){
        $('#content').css('overflow', 'scroll');
        console.log($('svg'));
    }

});
```

This is my **application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

    if defined?(Bundler)
      Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(assets: %w(development test)))
    end

    module Autumnlan
      class Application < Rails::Application
        config.encoding = "utf-8"
        config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false

        config.assets.enabled = true

        config.assets.version = '1.0'
      end
    end
```

this is my **development.rb**

```
Autumnlan::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.whiny_nils = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  config.assets.compress = false

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.compile = true
end
```

This is my **Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem "switch_user"
#gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
gem "ckeditor", "3.7.1"
gem 'squeel'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'thin'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'compass-rails'
```

These are my **installed gems**:

```
bundle show

Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.3)
  * actionpack (3.2.3)
  * activemodel (3.2.3)
  * activerecord (3.2.3)
  * activeresource (3.2.3)
  * activesupport (3.2.3)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * bbenezech-nested_form (0.0.6)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  * bootstrap-sass (2.0.4.0)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * chunky_png (1.2.6)
  * ckeditor (3.7.1)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * compass (0.12.2)
  * compass-rails (1.0.3)
  * daemons (1.1.9)
  * devise (2.1.2)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (0.12.10)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * fssm (0.2.9)
  * haml (3.1.7)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * hpricot (0.8.6)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.1.1)
  * jquery-ui-rails (1.1.1)
  * json (1.7.5)
  * kaminari (0.13.0)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.19)
  * modernizr-rails (2.0.6)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * orm_adapter (0.4.0)
  * pg (0.14.0)
  * polyamorous (0.5.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * quiet_assets (1.0.1)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-pjax (0.5.9)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.3)
  * rails_admin (0.0.5)
  * railties (3.2.3)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rb-readline (0.4.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * remotipart (1.0.2)
  * sass (3.2.1)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * squeel (1.0.9)
  * state_machine (1.1.2)
  * switch_user (0.8.0)
  * thin (1.4.1)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.7)
  * warden (1.2.1)
```

This is my **ruby environment**:

```
rvm info

ruby-2.0.0-p247@autumnlan:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux spugna 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, versione 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.14 () by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "2 days 21 hours 38 minutes 19 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/spugna/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p247"
    date:         "2013-06-27"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41674"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@autumnlan"
    ruby:         "/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@autumnlan/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@autumnlan/bin:/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/spugna/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@autumnlan"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@autumnlan:/home/spugna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    IRBRC:        "/home/spugna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "autumnlan"
```

Comment: What command are you trying to run? `rake assets:precompile`? And in which environment?

Comment: development environment. It happens both with 'compile on the fly' and 'rake assets precompile'

Comment: Try looking into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081832/how-do-i-precompile-assets-in-rails-in-development-environment) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: no changes. PS: edited question with environment and application configs

Comment: I'm sure it's not a programming error. It worked in a previous (not recoverable) config.

Answer (score 0):

In /config/environments/development.rb  , try setting:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: I mentioned the production environment by mistake. Try doing it in the development env.

Comment: This would probably break the dev environment because dev expects the assets to be compiled on the fly.  If you tell it to serve_static_assets, it might not find any assets.